# Changing edittext values right after typing something in it

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Can you change `edittext` values right after typing something in it? I want my input and output be on the same `edittext`. I've used `textwatcher` to get the input and to output it on the same `edittext`.

```
package com.example.lathrix.textwatcher;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextWatcher mid = null;
    EditText sat_amin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.asd);
    String satamin = sat_amin.getText().toString();
    int satamln = satamin.length();
    String last = satamin.substring(satamin.length() - 1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mid = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                switch(satamln){
                    case 1:
                        sat_amin.setText("12:0" +satamin + " AM");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (last == "p"){
                            sat_amin.setText("12:0" +satamin + " PM");
                        }else{
                            sat_amin.setText("12:" +satamin + " AM");
                        }
                        break;


                    default:
                        sat_amin.setText("");
                        break;



            }
        }



    };


    sat_amin.addTextChangedListener(mid);

    }

}
```

As you can see the program is for easy time encoding, I want it to output the interpreted time on the same `edittext` after typing. When I run the app it just crashes.

Comment: Your app crashes because you `afterTextChanged` keep calling it self, since you update the `editText` inside it

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because `afterTextChanged` keep calling it self, since you update the `editText` inside it, try removing `TextChangedListener` before inserting something like this :

```
 @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                int satamln=5;
                switch (satamln) {
                    case 1:
                        sat_amin.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        sat_amin.setText("12:0" + satamin + " AM");
                        sat_amin.addTextChangedListener(this);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        sat_amin.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        if (last == "p") {
                            sat_amin.setText("12:0" + satamin + " PM");
                        } else {
                            sat_amin.setText("12:" + satamin + " AM");
                        }
                        sat_amin.addTextChangedListener(this);
                        break;


                    default:
                        sat_amin.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        sat_amin.setText("");
                        sat_amin.addTextChangedListener(this);
                        break;


                }
            }
```

Hope this helps